# servlet connection to remote mysql

Tags: mysql, eclipse, tomcat, servlets, backend

I am trying to connect my java servlet program in local in eclipse IDE to my remote SQL database which is created in a web hosting.

AdminLoginServlet-

```
package dao;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import model.Model;

public class Dao 
{
     private  static String driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
     private static String url="jdbc:mysql://xyz.com/devadmin_CustomerDatabasev1";
     private static String username="USER";
     private static String password="Password";
     private static Connection con=null;
     private static ResultSet rs=null;
     public static Connection connect()
     {
          try
          {
              Class.forName(driver);
              con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,username, password);
          }
          catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
          {
                e.printStackTrace();
          }
          catch(SQLException e)
          {
               e.printStackTrace();
          }
          return con;
      }
      public static ResultSet validate(Model m, String sql)
      {
          try
          {
              connect();
              PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select userid,password from adminlogin where userid='user' and password='password'");
              rs=ps.executeQuery();
          }
          catch(SQLException e)
          {
               e.printStackTrace();
          }
          return rs;
     }
}
```

I get a 500 error code with the following error on UI-

```
`HTTP Status 500 -type Exception report message description 
 The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
dao.Dao.validate(Dao.java:40)
controller.AdminLoginServlet.doPost(AdminLoginServlet.java:41)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
```

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.47 logs.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
`
And following error on Console-

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at dao.Dao.connect(Dao.java:22)
at dao.Dao.validate(Dao.java:39)
at controller.AdminLoginServlet.doPost(AdminLoginServlet.java:41)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [AdminLoginServlet] in context with path [/FirstApp] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
at dao.Dao.validate(Dao.java:40)
at controller.AdminLoginServlet.doPost(AdminLoginServlet.java:41)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I am not sure how to proceed or debug the piece of code.Thanks in advance for any pointer that anyone can provide.

Edit:(26 th feb,2017)
I found the connector for java to mysql was missing from the following link:
http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/kathleen/classes/cs3200/JDBCtutorial.pdf

But I am not able to add it into build path as an external archive.I am getting following option-

[Check the folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shK3g.jpg)

Thanks in advance for any pointer that anyone can provide.

Comment: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` Where is it at runtime?

Comment: @nitin i have loaded it in lib and have attached the screenshot in the main question for reference..

Comment: 1. Put the driver jar file in the web app libraries, just like the other libraries you need at runtime (i.e. under WebContent/WEB-INF/lib). Remove it from the build path: all the web app libraries are implicitly in the build path. 2. Don't catch and ignore exceptions in connect(). All the NullPointerExceptions hide the original cause: you couldn't connect. If you can't connect, you shouldn't return from the connect() method. You should throw an exception. 3. There is a big chance that your hosting provider does not allow connections from outside its network.

Answer (score 0):

The database which you are connecting might not have values and also check the column names or you might have given the wrong name or you might not have included the respective jar file under WebContent folder.Take a keen look at all these.